# innerText of HTML is undefined, but shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, typeerror, undefined, innertext

The error is:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')
```

I get this error when I try to run my code.

```js
var addCart = document.getElementsByClassName("add-cart");

for (var i = 0; i < addCart.length; i++) {
  var button = addCart[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", addCartClicked);
}


function addCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target;
  var shopProducts = button.parentElement
  var title = shopProducts.getElementsByClass("product-title")[0].innerText;
  console.log(title);
}
```

```html
<h4 class="product-title">Breakfast Club Blue Hoodie</h4>
<div class="rating">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
<p>$55.00<i class="fa fa-cart-plus add-cart"></i></p>
</div>
```

I expected whats in "product-title" to appear on the console

Comment: it's `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: It's not saying that the innerText is undefined, it's saying that the element is undefined, so you can't get its innerText.

Comment: That must be a copying error, because that would cause the error message say that it undefined is not a function. @Pointy

Comment: The parent element is the p tag

Comment: Is there a wrapper element around the `h4`, `div`, and `p`? That's the element you should be setting `shopProducts` to.

Comment: @John Zhang Could you kindly accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent element of the icon that you click is the p tag, so you need to go up one more level.

```
var addCart = document.getElementsByClassName("add-cart");
for (var i = 0; i < addCart.length; i++){
    var button = addCart[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", addCartClicked);
}

function addCartClicked(event){
var button = event.target;
var shopProducts = button.parentElement
var grandParent = shopProducts.parentElement
var title = grandParent.getElementsByClassName("product-title")[0].innerText;
console.log(title);
}
```

or you could just do it like:

```
var shopProducts = button.parentElement.parentElement
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target;
  var shopProducts = button.parentElement
  var title = button.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerText;
  console.log(title);
}
```

This is not a good method but may help you get your result